# Two tangents of the circle $x^2+y^2=8$ at A and B meet at P (-4,0) then find the area of quadrilateral PAOB.

Tags: conic-sections

> Two tangents of the circle $x^2+y^2=8$ at $A$ and $B$ meet at $P =(-4,0)$ then find the area of quadrilateral $PAOB$.

Here, $O$ is the origin.

Distance of $P$ from $O$ is $4$ unit.

$$OA=OB=2\sqrt 2$$

Therefore 
$$OP^2=OA^2+AP^2$$
$$AP=2\sqrt 2$$

Hence $$\Delta POA=4$$
$$ar(PAOB)=8$$

This was a true of false question. I modified it a bit. Basically, the answer says the area is not 8sq unit. What am I doing wrong.

There is another sub question to this

> Is the area of quadrilateral formed by the tangents from an external point with length of tangent 2r?

From the way I have solved, I am inclined to say no, but since it says my answer is wrong, please help me verify this.

Comment: Why 8 isn't the answer?

Comment: I think your computation of the area is correct. Maybe there is something wrong in the solutions?

Comment: @Unknown that’s what I thought, but needed to get it checked anyway. Also, the second statement remains untrue too right?

Comment: @Aditya i am not quite sure, if I understand that subquestion right, but assuming that the "length of tangent" means the distance from $P$ to $A$ and $r$ is the radius of the circle I would say so, yes.

Comment: @Unknown 'Yes' means the statement is false?

Comment: @Aditya if my understanding of the question is correct, then I would say the statement is false. Sorry for confusing you.